# React mongodb error - cannot connect to mongodb table

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, nodemon

TypeError: signupTemplateCopy is not a constructor
my mongo database is successfully getting connected with react app. But when i try to insert data into the table from react, it is showing error. i created schema signupTemplate and imported it in routes by `const signupTemplateCopy = require('../models/models')` and further i created signupeduser to save the data from user. I think the problem is in routes.js in  `const signedupUser = new signupTemplateCopy({ Name: request.body.Name, Email:request.body.email, Password: request.body.Password})`. The program is taking signupTemplateCopy as a constructor.

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const routesURL = require('./routes/routes')
const cors = require('cors')  
dotenv.config()
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS, () => console.log("Database Connected"))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use('/app', routesURL)
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('server is up and running on 4000'))
```

models.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const signupTemplate = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: {
        type:String,
        required:true

    },
    Email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Password : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.export=mongoose.model('mytable',signupTemplate)
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const signupTemplateCopy = require('../models/models')

router.post('/signup', (request, response) => {
    const signedupUser = new signupTemplateCopy({
        Name: request.body.Name,
        Email:request.body.email,
        Password: request.body.Password
    })
    signedupUser.save()
    .then(data => {
        response.json(data)
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        response.json(error)
    })
})
module.exports = router
```

test.http (to test by sending request)

```
POST http://localhost:4000/app/signup
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Name": "joey",
    "Email": "abx@example.com",
    "Password": "xyz@123"
}
```

response

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2037
Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 09:52:13 GMT
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>TypeError: signupTemplateCopy is not a constructor<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\routes\routes.js:6:26<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.handle (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at router (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at cors (D:\E-commerce React\shopping\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:188:7)</pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time to figure this out. Your spelling for module.export is incorrect in your mongoose model.

Should be **exports**